# I've never seen anything like this? Random 403 on page elements after every refresh?

Tags: http-status-code-403

Does anyone know what is causing this? 
Will this be something on the server?

http://www.theprovincecontests.com/

Thanks

Comment: I see the same problem. I think their server is somehow misconfigured. Maybe they pull the files from a share which is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there's more than one server behind a reverse proxy/load balancer and (at least) one is misconfigured.